# What is the correct verb to describe the situation below?

Tags: verbs

> He calculated its value less than the expected value.

In this sentence I want to say that he made a mistake and the  value he calculated is less than expected value.Is my sentence correct or is there any verb to describe this situation? I mean can “less “use as an adjective here.

Comment: Less than the *expected* value or less than the *actual* value?

Answer (score 1):

It would be:

> He calculated its value ***at** less than the expected value*.

Making a prepositional phrase solves the problem.